# How to pass a variable as a path to Firestore database using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-applications

i been trying to use a variable as a path to access a collection data from my firestore database but I keep getting an error.

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private readonly firestore: Firestore) {
    this.user = this.authService.getUser();
    this.fullname = this.user.givenName + " " + this.user.familyName;
    console.log('user: ', this.fullname);

  }
  details$ = collectionData(collection(this.firestore, this.fullname)) as Observable<Details[]>;
```

Im trying the code above but it keeps giving me an error to access the path in Firestore.

```
 constructor(private authService: AuthService, private readonly firestore: Firestore) {
    this.user = this.authService.getUser();
    this.fullname = this.user.givenName + " " + this.user.familyName;
    console.log('user: ', this.fullname);

  }
  details$ = collectionData(collection(this.firestore, “students”)) as Observable<Details[]>;
```

If I don’t use the variable this.fullname it works.

[This is the error im getting on conosle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaDrb.png)
[This is what i currently have on the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFoMP.png)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore database (from the console)?

Comment: Im currently using the google auth as the sign in method. I’m also using firestore database in which the collection ID is the user given name and the user family name. I made a variable that hold those but I cannot use it as the path to my firestore collection. Will share the screen shots asap !